# How to detect jQuery $.get failure?

Tags: jquery

I'm a jQuery beginner. I'm trying to code a very simple using $.get(). The [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#) says:

> If a request with jQuery.get() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError()  method or.
>
> As of jQuery 1.5, the .error() method of the jqXHR object
> returned by jQuery.get() is also available for error handling.

So, if all goes well, my callback function for success will be called. However, if the request fails, I would like to get the HTTP code :404, 502, etc and formulate a meaningful error message for the user.

However, since this is an asynchronous call I can imagine that I might have several outstanding. How would .ajaxError() know which request it corresponds to?  Maybe it would be better to use the .error() method of the jqXHR object returned by jQuery.get()?

I am seeking an extremely simple code example. Perhaps the success routine calls Alert("Page found") and the failure routine checks for 404 and does an Alert("Page not found").

### Update

The following page is extremely helpful: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You're right that you can use jQuery 1.5's new jqXHR to assign error handlers to `$.get()` requests.  This is how you can do it:

```
var request = $.get('/path/to/resource.ext');

request.success(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});

request.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  if (textStatus == 'timeout')
    console.log('The server is not responding');

  if (textStatus == 'error')
    console.log(errorThrown);

  // Etc
});
```

You can also chain handlers directly onto the call:

```
$.get('/path/to/resource.ext')
     .success(function(result) { })
     .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { });
```

I prefer the former to keep the code less tangled, but both are equivalent.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help. But what if I have several requests active in parallel? How can I tell which error belongs to which?

Comment: The jqXHR object passed into the error handler will contain information about the original request that raised the error. Depending on your server-side implementation, errorThrown will also contain more detail about what went wrong.

Comment: +1 Thanks again. So much to learn, alas. Btw, how do I pass CGI parameters to the URL.  E.g google.com?serach="pizza"

Comment: If you pass a JavaScript object as `$.get()`'s second parameter, it will URL encode that data and append it to the URL.  For your example, you'd use `$.get('/path/to/resource.ext', { search: 'pizza' });` to add the parameter.

Comment: jQuery now uses .done and .fail instead of .success and .error which have both been deprecated but will probably work for some time. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: @Jazzepi is right, but there's also this alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 33):

As of jQuery 3.0 `.success()` and `.error()` are deprecated.
You can use `.done()` and `.fail()` instead

```
$.get( url )
    .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown );
    });
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 18):

`.get()` is just a synonym for `.ajax()` with a number of options pre-set. Use [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get the full range of options, including the `error` callback.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "test.htm",
error: function(xhr, statusText) { alert("Error: "+statusText); },
success: function(msg){ alert( "Success: " + msg ); }
}
);
```

Comment: +1That shows what a n00b I am that I did not know that. I'll try it out and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, how do I pass CGI parameters to the URL.  E.g google.com?serach="pizza"

Comment: Ajax requests that fail in transport will fail silently (error only gets called if there's an error parsing your request, but it was properly received)