# JQuery not loading data when $.get is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

Experimenting with JS/Jquery and the JQuery .get function. I'm getting the pop up/alert to open but there is no text after "Data Loaded:"

What am I missing?

I have a .js file (called lab1.js) that looks like this:

```
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    person + "'s Favorite Links:";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("/Users/rabdelaz/Desktop/Labs/lab1.txt", function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
});
```

With the following in my lab1.txt file:

```
"a line of text of your choosing"
```

Finally here is my html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lab1.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Lab 1</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.akamai.com">www.akamai.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://aloha.akamai.com">aloha.akamai.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://agora.akamai.com">agora.akamai.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://ask.akamai.com">ask.akamai.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://luau.akamai.com">luau.akamai.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://mydrive.akamai.com">mydrive.akamai.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://act.akamai.com">act.akamai.com</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://tools.gss.akamai.com/portal">GSS Tools</a></li>
        </ul>

        <script src="lab1.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You running this off the file protocol?

Comment: Is the file path to lab1.txt correct? If it's in the same directory as lab1.js, then just write it as `lab1.txt` instead of `/Users/.../lab1.txt`.

Comment: running the file from local server??

Comment: @radcliffejh Wouldn't solve the underlying issue, though.

Comment: Wow, jQuery 1.3.2?!! Party likes it's 1999! You should use a current version

Comment: If you pop up the developers tools in your browser (ctrl+shift+J in some browsers), there may be a network tab where you can see what happens to that get request.  Also, consider adding a .fail() to your get request, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047906/how-to-detect-jquery-get-failure-seeking-simple-code-example

Comment: @epascarello: file protocol? I don't believe so. I don't know what that is/what you mean.

Comment: Are you clicking a file on your computer [e.g. file://C:/Users/foo...] or is it being run off a server [e.g. `http://localhost/...`]?

Comment: @radcliffejh: Path is correct. I've also tried without the fully qualified name since the file is in the same directory as lab1.js.

Comment: @MacSupport: I could use a newer version but it should work with this version according to my lab. Will try to rule that out.

Comment: @Paul: thanks, will look at that more closely soon.

Comment: @epascarello: I'm opening the file locally in my webrowser. No server involved here. Everything is local. So yes in the address bar it's file://Users....

Comment: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Comment: for the mac: http://blog.derraab.com/2013/05/30/start-google-chrome-with-local-file-access-on-mac-os-x/