# Turn click search into instant search using Partial View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which on button click will return a view of search results based on the given searchString.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search"))
{
    <div id="search" class="input-group">
        @Html.TextBox("searchString", null, new { @id = "searchBox", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" })
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This calls the Index action on the Search controller which gets results based on the searchString and populates a list of strongly typed model "SearchView"

```
public ViewResult Index(string searchString = "", int startIndex = 0, int pageSize = 5)
{
    List<SearchView> searchResults = 
        (from p in db.Products
         where p.code.Contains(searchString)
         select new { ID = p.ID, Table = "Product", Name = p.code, Controller = "Product" })
             .ToList()
             .Select(x => new SearchView { ID = x.ID, Table = x.Table, Name = x.Name, Controller = x.Controller }).ToList();

    searchResults.AddRange(
        (from p in db.Multimedias
         where p.name.Contains(searchString)
         where p.isActive == true
         select new { ID = p.ID, Table = "Image", Name = p.name, Controller = "Multimedia" })
             .ToList()
             .Select(x => new SearchView { ID = x.ID, Table = x.Table, Name = x.Name, Controller = x.Controller }).ToList()); 

    ViewBag.startIndex = startIndex;
    ViewBag.pageSize = pageSize;
    ViewBag.loadMore = searchResults.Count > startIndex + pageSize;

    return View(searchResults.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize));
}
```

The view then gets called which is simply a table list of results

```
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Table)</b><br />
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", item.Controller, new { @ID = item.ID }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
@if (ViewBag.LoadMore)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b> @Html.ActionLink("See more results...", "Index", "Search", new { @startIndex = ViewBag.startIndex + ViewBag.pageSize }, null)</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**My question is given this, how would I convert the view into a partial view and change the form so that it shows the partial view on each key press in the textbox?**

EDIT: The accepted answer can work but required me to return a partial view and on the javascript use keyup rather than keypress along with removing whitespace to create a valid URL.

```
return PartialView("_Search", searchResults.Skip(startIndex).Take(pageSize));

$("#searchBox").keyup(function () {      
    $("#myPartialViewContainer").load('@Url.Action("IndexLive","Search")' + '?searchString=' + $('#searchBox').val() + '&startIndex=0' + '&pageSize=5');
});
```

Comment: You will need javascript/jquery and ajax. [This question.answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142422/rendering-partial-view-on-button-click-in-asp-net-mvc/29142790#29142790) should help you get started. Its does the 'search' on a button click but you could just as easily handle textbox `.keyup()` event (but I think once your try it you will probably stick with a button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax load instead of form submit to load your partial view.

### View

1. Create partial view container to hold the partial view result.
2. In jquery textbox key press event, just call the partial view and loads in partial view container .

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search"))
   {
        <div id="search" class="input-group">
          @Html.TextBox("searchString", null, new { @id = "searchBox", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search" })
          <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
         </div>
         </div>

       <!--Hold partial view content-->
           <div id="myPartialViewContainer">        
           </div>

       <!--Include jquery-->
       <!--Scripts to help load partial view content in partial view container-->
           @section Scripts
            {
            $( document ).ready(function() {
               // On each key press this will execute
               $('#searchBox').keyup(function(e) { 
               // Following will load partial view in partial view container
               $("#myPartialViewContainer").load('@Url.Action("Search","Index")' + '?searchString =' + $('#searchBox').val()+ '&startIndex =0' + '&pageSize =5');

            });
            });
            }
    }
   ```

Comment: `.live()`??? It was depreciated in v1.7 and removed in v1.9. - it just needs to be `$('#searchBox').keyup(function() {`

Comment: Thanks with some little tweaks I got this answer to work, the search controller also needs to return a PartialView rather than a View, and keyup rather than keypress needs to be used as it doesn't register the latest character otherwise.