# after jquery table.load() html element becomes undefined

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dom

I am rewriting the post to make it clearer

I have a HomeController that has the following Actions

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        MapDetailsRepository repMapDetail = new MapDetailsRepository("name=ge");
        YearRepository repYear = new YearRepository("name=ge");


        SuperMapModel smM = new SuperMapModel();
        smM.saVM = new StudentAssessmentViewModel();

        MapDetailResultSet mapDetailResultSet = repMapDetail.GetMapDetails(53);

        smM.saVM.mapDetails = mapDetailResultSet.mapDetails.ToList();
        smM.saVM.results = mapDetailResultSet.results.ToList();
        smM.saVM.students = mapDetailResultSet.students.ToList();

        smM.scM = new SearchControlViewModel();
        smM.scM.YearList = new SelectList(repYear.GetAll(), "yearID", "year");


        return View(smM);        }

public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(string searchText) {
         MapDetailsRepository repMapDetail = new MapDetailsRepository("name=ge");
         SuperMapModel smM = new SuperMapModel();
        smM.saVM = new StudentAssessmentViewModel();

        MapDetailResultSet mapDetailResultSet = repMapDetail.GetMapDetails(22);

        smM.saVM.mapDetails = mapDetailResultSet.mapDetails.ToList();
        smM.saVM.results = mapDetailResultSet.results.ToList();
        smM.saVM.students = mapDetailResultSet.students.ToList();

        return PartialView("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", smM.saVM);
}
```

SuperMapModel is a Super Class that has 2 view models 
- scM for search panel partial control
- saVM for MapDetailList partial control

On Page load SuperMapModel is passed to the View which passes the respective models to each partial control

```
<div>
@Html.Partial("_SearchPanel", Model.scM)
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive" >
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Maps/_MapDetailsList.cshtml", Model.saVM)

</div>
```

My MapDetails PArtial Control is very complicated so i am giving a stripped down version

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th/><th/><th/></tr>
        <tr><th/><th/><th/></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach(ShortStudent geStudent in Model.students)
     {  
        <tr>
           <td>@geStudent.firstname</td>
           foreach (run it x number of times)
            {
               <td>
                   @foreach (ShortResult geResult in Model.results)
                   {
                   if (geResult.ResultValue != null)
                                {

                                    <script>{ setResultValue(@colIndex, @rowIndex, '@geResult.ResultValue'); }</script>
                                }
                      }
               </td>
           }
       </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This setResultValue function is defined on the main view (About) and it sets the innerhtml of current td

```
function setResultValue(colIndex, rowIndex, resultValue) {
    alert("inside about");
    var cell = $("#MapDetails").children().children()[rowIndex].children[colIndex];
    cell.innerHTML = resultValue;

}
```

P.S. This grid is converted to a kendo grid on document.ready

Now it works perfectly on page load but when i click search button from inside searchpanel i do the following (defined on searchpanel partial control)

```
function refreshGrid() {
    alert("search panel");
    var url = '@Url.Action("DisplaySearchResults", "Home")';
    $("#MapDetails").load(url, { searchText: "Lee" }, function () {
        alert("success");
    });

}
```

P.S. The call-back here is never fired

So now i am binding only the partial view with the new data in **DisplaySearchResults**

Now obviously it does not find the script function setResultValue on main page so i duplicated the same script function setResultValue on partial view mapdetailslist (which is ofcourse a bad practice)

**UPDATE**

After debugging i got some more detail so Now the newer problem is on page load i can get 
$("#MapDetails").children().children()[rowIndex]
but after button click the same is undefined

Comment: What do you mean _something is crashing_? What is happening? What errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: nothing happens on button click

Comment: Debug your code in the browser. Is you script even being hit? (and get rid of the awful `onclick` in your button and give it a id so you can use `$('#yourButtonID').click(function() { ...` as per the linked answer.

Comment: trying now.....

Comment: My html table calls a script (that sets cell values in table) that is present in the About.cshtml page and is properly called on load but when i click the search button it is not called.. the DisplaySearchResults function is however fired and therefore the new grid is loaded without any data

Comment: If you have a script that does something when the page is loaded, then you need to run that script again in the success callback. And you also need to destroy the existing `kendoGrid` and reattach it in the success callback - `$("#MapDetails").load(url, {searchText : "Sophie"}, function() { // call your scripts here });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138774/discussion-between-samra-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that i could not get the td element with the following code

```
$("#MapDetails").children().children()[rowIndex]
```

I have solved it in a very hacky way but would love to have a neater solution

```
function setResultValue(colIndex, rowIndex, resultValue) {

if ($("#MapDetails").children().children()[rowIndex] != undefined) {
    var cell = $("#MapDetails").children().children()[rowIndex].children[colIndex];
    cell.innerHTML = resultValue;
}
else {
    var newRow = 0, newCol = 0, assessmentLength = 5, elementPos = 0;
    newRow = rowIndex - 3;
    newCol = colIndex - 4;

    elementPos = (newRow * assessmentLength) + newCol;
    $(".test").get(elementPos).innerHTML = resultValue;

}
}
```

.test is the class of my td as you could see in the markup

My Question on the sequence of loading script element and dom element when partial view rendering is still there