# MVC - Returning partial view is creating a new page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a form with some input fields. When a user clicks on the submit I want to post the fields back, use them to query a service and load some results into a view on the same page while preserving the original input. For this, I've scaffolded a view using my model and added a partial view below to populate the results with.

```
....bottom of form <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list-group">
    @Html.Partial("_ResultsPartial")
</div>
```

In my controller, I have 2 actions, one to create the initial view and one for the post back.

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Enter search details";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public PartialViewResult Search(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        List<SearchResult> results = new List<SearchResult>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //await go off and do the actaul search
           results = _dataProvider.GetData(searchCriteria);
        }
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_ResultsPartial.cshtml", results);
    }
```

So in order to render the partial view, I use return PartialView passing in the new model which contains the results of my search. One of the problems I'm having with this is that creates a new page, i.e. the partial view doesn't load on the existing page. What other way is there to render a partial view while in a controller action so that the partial view loads on the page it was created?

Comment: Use ajax to call a method that returns your partial view, and update the existing page.

Comment: Sounds ok. But i'm really looking for the path of least resistance. This is not production code. With my given setup at the moment is there an even easier way

Comment: Refer [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142422/rendering-partial-view-on-button-click-in-asp-net-mvc/29142790#29142790)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your rendering with something like:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Results", new {results = model.Results})};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
return PartialView("_ResultsPartial", results);
```