# MVC Core How to use select DropDownlist then shows the appropriate field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Need help here.

So I have this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Nationality, new SelectList(Model.NationalityList.Select(s => s.NationalityName)), "-- Please Select --")
```

Which shows the list of Nationality. I am just wondering how do I generate a table based on the selection nationality.

So for example I have something like

```
@if (Model.Nationality == "Japan")
{
Shows the code here for example another table
}
```

In ASP.NET Webform, when we select the DropDownlist, we can do autopostback and then generate the form below. How to do it in MVC Core?

Thanks

Comment: You use ajax to post the selected value to a method which returns a partial view (or `JsonResult`) of your table and update the DOM.

Comment: You will probably have to use an Ajax call to the server whenever a new select option gets selected.

Comment: Autopostback in fact uses ajax call to render different values on same page, the same concept also available in MVC (you can pass values to action method using ajax call by adding parameters).

Comment: Thank you so much guys. Looks like I need to learn AJAX now.Thanks

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142422/rendering-partial-view-on-button-click-in-asp-net-mvc/29142790#29142790) for a typical example