# Linking an anchor tag in a parent table with a detail table using its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to show a list of customers in a table on the top of a page, each customer having a button at its last column which once clicked, will show/hide a detail table under the customers table. I have all my data available from the moment I load the page, since I'm using

```
@model List<CustomerData>
```

for my model in the View and `CustomerData` is a model class which contains the details for each customer.

```
public class CustomerData : ModeloBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

My idea was to set up the id of the  element (the button) with the customer ID, like this:

```
<a class="fa fa-bar-chart menu-icon test-button-1" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="@customer.ID"></a>
```

This will be inside a Razor foreach of the list of customers, so that each customer button element to show its details will have the ID of each customer.

However, I have no idea how to get the ID of the recently clicked button so that I can do another foreach in the view to obtain the Details of the customer whose ID matches the recently clicked button ID:

```
@foreach (var detail in Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == 'how?').Details)
```

and then be able to show them on the second table.

I'm extremely rusty in MVC and Javascript/jQuery so I'd appreciate any help and guidance on the matter in case I'm going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Are you initially rendering all the `Details` for each `Customer` (and hiding them)? Otherwise you need to use ajax to call a server method that return a partial view of your details (Razor is server side code and is executed before the view is sent to the browser)

Comment: is it that you want to show the details of one customer while you click on a button or to show everyones details together?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not rendering them all and hiding them, but I do have them at my disposal already since they're a property of my model so I don't need to go back to the server again. If I was able to store the ID of the recently clicked button and then using it on Razor, I could just show the details right then with the foreach. If Ajax + PartialView is a much better idea, I'd try to change my method.

Comment: Of course you need to go back to the server if your not rendering them all. Your code is executed on the server and it generates a page which is sent to the client. The client is then disconnected from the server. It has no knowledge of your model(s) or c# code

Comment: @PrashanthBenny I have a list of customers, for example A and B which are shown in a table. The last column for each customer is a button which will show up a details table with extra data for each customer. I only want to show the details for a customer when the user clicks on its button.

Comment: Replace `id="@customer.ID"` with `data-id="@customer.ID"` and add a script with `$('.yourButtonClass').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('id'); //make ajax call })` and then refer the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142422/rendering-partial-view-on-button-click-in-asp-net-mvc/29142790#29142790) for a typical example of adding a partial view to the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was able to add a partial view which successfully shows the ID of the customer (first step to test it works) as you click on the button, under the main table. Unfortunately, the way this second table is going to work regarding styles and JS (shows/hides based on a css class) doesn't work when it's inside a partial view. There's a JS inside the parent view that handles the click event and toggles based on the class, but since the class has to be in the partial view, when the event fires the element with the class has not been rendered yet since it's in the partial.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm afraid this means there's not an easy way of doing this with a partial view and that it'd probably be easier to render everything on load and hide / show things after each click. Whatcha think?

Comment: If you want to handle events for dynamically added elements the you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of the recently clicked button like so:

```
var customerIdClicked = null;
$('a.menu-icon').on('click' , function(e){
     customerIdClicked = $(e.target).attr('id'); 
    /* customerIdClicked is the id of the anchor clicked. You can now use 
       customerIdClicked to query your database. */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<a class="fa fa-bar-chart menu-icon test-button-1" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="@customer.ID" onclick ="Details(@customer.ID)"></a>

 <script>
      function Details(x)
      {
         var id = x;
         // Write your script here for showing details
      }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Razor generates the page before the html is rendered. so you cannot call a function using razor after the page is rendered.

The best way to show the details of a particular button click will be using AJAX.

You could **call a function on click** of the button like

```
<a class="fa fa-bar-chart menu-icon test-button-1" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" id="@customer.ID" onClick="getDetails(@customer.ID);"></a>
```

and then **write** the getDetails **function to call the ajax method**

```
<script>
    function getDetails(int Id){
        $.ajax({
        url: "yourWebsiteURL/customer/GetDetails/"+Id, 
        success: function(result){
            //Display the result
        }
        });
    }

</script>
```

in the customer controller write a function to retrieve the details

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetDetails(int Id)
{
    var detail = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == Id).Details;
    var DetailsJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(detail);
    return DetailsJson;
}
```

hope this helps.