# PartialView shows up and goes away on button click mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm following off the same problem as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142422/rendering-partial-view-on-button-click-in-asp-net-mvc). However i'm getting the partial view results in the view except that on the click of the button the partial view results shows and goes away instantly.

**Model Class**

```
public class Role
{
    public string Employee_ID { get; set; }

    public string CPR { get; set; }
    public string Dept_Name { get; set; }
    public string Employee_Name { get; set; }

    //User Role
    public string UserRoleName { get; set; }     
}
```

**Main View Class**

*This is the main view class that accepts Employee_ID as an input and returns 3 model class as output i.e. CPR, Dept_Name and Employee_Name*

```
public ActionResult CPanelDeleteRole()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CPanelDeleteRole(Role rol)
{

    GetUserInfo(rol);
    return View(rol);
}

public void GetUserInfo(Role rol)
{
    connection();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("GetUserRoleInfo", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", rol.Employee_ID);
    com.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    com.Parameters.Add("@CPR", SqlDbType.Int, 12);
    com.Parameters.Add("@DeptName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
    com.Parameters["@EmployeeName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    com.Parameters["@CPR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    com.Parameters["@DeptName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    con.Open();

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    rol.Employee_Name = com.Parameters["@EmployeeName"].Value.ToString();
    rol.CPR = com.Parameters["@CPR"].Value.ToString();
    rol.Dept_Name = com.Parameters["@DeptName"].Value.ToString();
}
```

**Partial View Class**

*This is the partial view class that accepts the Employee_ID input value and returns as string parameter for querying a list*

```
public ActionResult TableData(string searchText)
{
    connection();
    var userrole = new List<Role>();
    string query = "SELECT USER_ROLES.Role_ID, ROLES_LOOKUP.Role_Type FROM HelpDesk.dbo.ROLES_LOOKUP, HelpDesk.dbo.USER_ROLES WHERE USER_ROLES.Username = @EmployeeID AND USER_ROLES.Role_ID = ROLES_LOOKUP.Role_ID";

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskDBContext"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", searchText);
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    userrole.Add(new Role
                    {
                        UserRoleName = sdr["Role_Type"].ToString(),
                            UserRoleID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Role_ID"].ToString())
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return PartialView("_TablePartial", userrole);
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h4 class="title">Delete Role</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee_ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label></label>
                                        <button id="GetRoleTable"  class="form-control btn btn-danger btn-fill pull-left">submit</button>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>الاسم</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="یوزرنیم" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Employee_Name)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>الرقم الشخصي</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="یوزرنیم" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CPR)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>الشعبة</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="یوزرنیم" value="@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Dept_Name)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="AddRoleTable"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("TableData", "Admin")';
    $('#GetRoleTable').click(function() {
        var empID = $('#Employee_ID').val();
        $('#AddRoleTable').load(url, { searchText: empID });
    })
</script>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model IEnumerable<ITHelpDesk.Models.Role>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserRoleName)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

[This is the gif image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUa0q.gif)

Comment: Because `<button id="GetRoleTable" ...>` is a submit button, so you make an ajax call, but then immediately submit and redirect. Add the `type="button" attribute.

Comment: Thanks once again. Its working now but i also have to return the three model class as described above which is not working.